# Is finding a Polytime reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$ equivalent to proving $L_2 \in P \Rightarrow L_1 \in P$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, logic, polynomial-time, polynomial-time-reductions

I often hear NP-completeness as problems such that, if they were in $P$ all problems in $NP$ are in $P$. The true definition, though, is that NP-complete is a set of languages in NP that all languages in NP reduce to in polynomial time.

But is this idea that NP-completeness implies all problems are in P if they are in P all encompassing? Of course, it works for other problems in NP, but let's take a problem in, say, EXPTIME, which P is known to be a proper subset of.

Is it correct to say that there is a polynomial time reduction from a language $A$ and a language $B$ in EXPTIME, if and only if $B \in P \Rightarrow A \in P$? How about the inverse? $B$ (in EXPTIME) reduces to $A$ iff $A \in P \Rightarrow B \in P$? And of course, what about the general case?

Comment: Also note: I am talking about Turing reductions in polytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this only works one way.

If there is a polynomial time reduction from $A$ to $B$, then $B \in P \implies A \in P$. This works irrespective of the what kind of languages $A$ and $B$ are.

The converse is not true. For example, take two languages $A, B \notin P$ such that there is *no* polynomial time reduction from $A$ to $B$ (these exist by the time hierarchy theorem). Then it still holds that $B \in P \implies A \in P$, since both sides of the implication are false.